# How to find out the subclass from the base class instance?

Tags: java, oop, reflection, inheritance

Is there a way to find out the name of derived class from a base class instance?

e.g.:

```
class A{
    ....
}
class B extends A{
    ...
}
class c extends A{
    ...
}
```

now if a method returns an object of `A`, can I find out if it is of type `B` or `C`?

Comment: Note that [type sniffing](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=3) is a bit of a code smell. It's not always the wrong thing to do, but it is the wrong approach often enough that you should take a close look at your design. If possible, rely on polymorphism (but see also Steve Yegge's [When Polymorphism Fails](http://sites.google.com/site/steveyegge2/when-polymorphism-fails)).

Comment: baseInstance.getClass().getName()

Answer (score 25, accepted):

using either `instanceof` or `Class#getClass()`

```
A returned = getA();

if (returned instanceof B) { .. }
else if (returned instanceof C) { .. }
```

`getClass()` would return either of: `A.class`, `B.class`, `C.class`

Inside the if-clause you'd need to downcast - i.e.

```
((B) returned).doSomethingSpecificToB();
```

---

That said, sometimes it is considered that using `instanceof` or `getClass()` is a bad practice. You should use [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_polymorphism) to try to avoid the need to check for the concrete subclass, but I can't tell you more with the information given.

Comment: A note on using polymorphism in this situation: You could have a method `getType()` or something similar in the implementation of `A` and override that method in `B` and `C`. Since all methods are virtual in java, a call to `getType()` would resolve the specific subtype.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using `instanceof`

e.g.

```
Class A aDerived= something.getSomethingDerivedFromClassA();

if (aDerived instanceof B) {

} else if (aDerived instanceof C) {

}

//Use type-casting where necessary in the if-then statement.
```

Answer (score 4):

Short answer to your question

> Is there a way to find out the derived class's name from a base class object?

**no**, the super-class has no way of telling the name/type of a sub-class.

You have to interrogate the object (which is an instance of a sub-class) and ask if it is an: `instanceof` a particular sub-class, or call it's `getClass()` method.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in the subclass' constructor

```
class A {
    protected String classname;
    public A() { this.classname = "A"; }
    public String getClassname() { return this.classname; }
}
class B extends A {
    public B() {
        super();
        this.classname = "B";
    }
}
```

So

```
A a = new A();
a.getClassname(); // returns "A"
B b = new B();
b.getClassname(); // returns "B"
((A)b).getClassname(); // Also returns "B"
```

Because it is casted into an "A" object, it will call the "A" `getClassname()` function but will return a value set by the constructor that was the "B" constructor.

Note: Call `super();` before setting it

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways I can think of
1) One with Using the Java reflection API
2) Other one would be with the instanceOf

Other method can be a Comparing objects to objects, I dont know how it might be, you can try this

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to find out the name of derived class from a base class instance?

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49107655/8524301), you can use this **extremely simple** approach.

```
abstract class A {
    public final String getName() {
         return this.getClass().getName();
    }
}

class B extends A { }

class C extends A { }
```

then simply print the current `class` name:

```
B b = new B();
C c = new C();

System.out.println(b.getName());
System.out.println(c.getName());
```

Output:

```
com.test.B
com.test.C
```

There is no need to store additional `Strings`, check `instanceof` or `override` the method in any subclass.

Answer (score 0):

A more modern approach (Java 16+) would be using pattern matching for the instanceof operator. The syntax is pretty simple:

```java
if(x instanceof X xChild){
    // use xChild
}
```

It is both shorter and less error-prone as it combines all the steps of testing the runtime type of the variable(`x` in the example above), casting it down, and assigning it to a new variable(`xChild in the example above). [Read more](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/language/pattern-matching-instanceof-operator.html).

Another example:

```java
    public void addUIControl(UIControl control) {
        if(control instanceof SelectList sl){
            selectList = sl;
        }
        else if(control instanceof TextBox tb){
            textBox = tb;
        }
        else if(control instanceof Button btn){
            button = btn;
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Uknown UIControl object has been passed to the SendFormMediator");
        }
    }
```