# Java inheritance: How can you find which subclass an object belongs to?

Tags: java, inheritance

I wasn't quite sure how to word it in the title, but here is the use case.

I have a class Test. Test has an attribute called Letter as so

```
public class Test() {
    Letter x;
}
```

Letter can be one of several subclasses.

```
class A()
class B()
class C()
```

Now suppose that in a class (let's call it driver), I have an instance of Test. I want to figure out whether this Test's letter is A, B, C, etc. so that I can access attribute unique to the child class. See:

```
public class Driver() {
    Test t;
}
```

If I use t.getClass(), will I get Class.Test, or will I get the child class (e.g. Class.A)? Is it possible for the Driver class to know x's subclass?

Is it possible to create a method like:

```
public Class getSubclassFromLetter(Letter x) {
    // Find subclass from the letter
}
```

Comment: "If I use t.getClass()" - well, what happens when you try?

Comment: *"so that I can access attribute unique to the child class."* Then your design is bad. One of the most important OO principles is *information hiding* which basically means that no other class knows what properties an object has.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find out the subclass from the base class instance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856122/how-to-find-out-the-subclass-from-the-base-class-instance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `instanceof`. It is not really a good practice to do that, but you can do the following:

```
if (x instanceof A) {
    //TODO whatever related to A
}
```

Answer (score 1):

using either `instanceof` or `Class#getClass()`

```
A returned = getA();

if (returned instanceof B) { .. }
else if (returned instanceof C) { .. }
```

`getClass()` would return either of: `A.class`, `B.class`, `C.class`

That said, sometimes it is considered that using `instanceof` or `getClass()` is a bad practice.