# Getting current Activity name from base class

Tags: android, android-activity

How can I get the name of the current activity in the base class.
Suppose I have a base activity class BaseActivity :

```
class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    ...
    String getCurrentActivityName() {
            ....
    }
    ...
}
```

Now I have 2 other classes

```
class Activity1 extends BaseActivity
{
    ....
}

class Activity2 extends BaseActivity
{
    ....
}
```

There maybe many more activities extending BaseActivity, for brevity I have used 2 here.

I am not sure how to implement getCurrentActivityName() method in the base class. It should return a String containing the name of the current activity.

EDIT : For some reasons I cannot edit Activity1 and Activity2.

Comment: @payloc this is useful when I am sure how many classes have extended the BaseActivity. But there is no fixed number. I will edit the question.

Comment: @payloc but I dont have a instance in my case right? how can i use instanceOf or .getClass() ??

Comment: @UtkarshSrivastava found a  way to do it that was missing in the question I previously marked as duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a new activity class you should add classname to the constructor and then get it with `getCurrentActivityName` method as you were trying

```
class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    {
        protected String className;
        public BaseActivity() { this.className = "BaseActivity"; }
        String getCurrentActivityName() {
              return this.className;
        }
        ...
    }

    class Activity1 extends BaseActivity
    {
        protected String className;
        public Activity1() { this.className = "Activity1"; }
    }

    class Activity2 extends BaseActivity
    {   
        protected String className;
        public Activity2() { this.className = "Activity2"; }

    }
```

Then if you call

```
BaseActivity baseActivity = new BaseActivity();
baseActivity.getClassname(); // returns "BaseActivity"
Activity1 activity1 = new Activity1();
activity1.getClassname(); // returns "Activity1"
```

Or if you just want to know the current activity name use . It's as simple as that

```
this.getClass().getSimpleName()
```

Comment: Please see edit in the question. I cannot edit the classes Activity1 and Activity2 for some reasons.

Comment: then just use the last line of code in my answer and get the current activity showing or else you need to edit your children classes as i see it

Comment: @payloc yes, i'm giving op two options including what you mentioned

Comment: 1+ for the latter

Comment: yepp, my bad... saw it at the last second

Comment: @payloc don't worry! appreciate +1

Answer (score 1):

Create abstract method `getActivityName()` in `BaseActivity`.

Implement `getActivityName()` in each activity and return `Activity.this.getClass().getSimpleName();`

Add this

```
String getCurrentActivityName() {
    return getActivityName();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this works fine, and I'm surprised the question I previously marked [as already having an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856122/how-to-find-out-the-subclass-from-the-base-class-instance) did not mention that within the accepted response.

```
abstract class A {
    public final String getName() {
         return this.getClass().getName();
    }
}

class B extends A { }

class C extends A { }
```

This prints the current `class` name of the implementing instance

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    B b = new B();
    C c = new C();

    System.out.println(b.getName());
    System.out.println(c.getName());
}
```

Output:

```
com.test.B
com.test.C
```

You can adapt it to your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ActivityType currentActivityType;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    String getCurrentActivityName(){
        switch (this.currentActivityType){
            case type1:
                return "Activity 1";
            case type2:
                return "Activity 2";
                default:
                    return "Base Activity";
        }

    }
}

enum ActivityType{
    type1,
    type2
}

public class FirstActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        currentActivityType = ActivityType.type1;
    }
}

public class SecondActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        currentActivityType = ActivityType.type2;
    }

}
```